# Laravel not picking up my table columns? - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

i'm trying to retrieve a column from my database with laravel.. i've confirmed the column actually exists but apparently laravel doesn't think the same.. any help? thanks!

The error is the following..

```
"Property [Salt] does not exist on this collection instance."
```

accounts model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class accounts extends Authenticatable
    {
        protected $table = "accounts";

        public $pkey = 'id';

        protected $salt = 'Salt';

        protected $fillable = ['id', 'Username', 'Key'];

        public $timestamps = false;
    }
```

CustomAuthController.php:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Auth;


class CustomAuthController extends Controller
{
    //Login
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|max:255',
            'Key' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        $user= User::where('Username', '=', $request->username)->get();

        $hashedpw = hash('whirlpool', $request->Key);

        if(Auth::attempt(['Username' => $request->username, 'Key' => $request->Key]))
        {
            return 'Logged in successfully';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'error'. $request->username. ' '.  $user->Salt; #problematic variable <-
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!
Jack

Hi, Again.. I've narrowed down the problem although i cant figure out how to fix it.. If my account isn't logged in on my website i cant seem to access the salt column. But, if i'm logged into the site i can select it?..

Comment: what is         protected $salt = 'Salt';
 ??

Comment: maybe you should change `"Salt"` to `"salt"`

Comment: "Property [salt] does not exist on this collection instance." get the same error, sorry.. i forgot to remove that var

Comment: Please show the migration file for this table. Did you show the whole `User` class?

Comment: I didn't migrate the existing database, do i need to do that? sorry im kinda new, i thought you could just hook up the tablename and then fetch the columns like that

Answer (score 1):

use `first()` instead of `get()` -

```
 $user= User::where('Username', '=', $request->username)->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [@Sohel0415 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48489225/3121398), your query returns collection not a single user model. You should use `first()` instead of `get()`

Also your `salt` property visibility identifier is `protected`, you should change this to `public` for access property from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You have Salt defined as `protected $salt`

so try `$user->salt;`

and it should work fine.

Comment: "Property [salt] does not exist on this collection instance." get the same error, sorry.. i forgot to remove that var

Comment: Well, looks like you don't have the ``salt`` defined in your model. you can also change the protected to public to make the $salt available